# How do I create a wiki entry to share knowledge with the community?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)
>   [What is this “answer your own question” jazz?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz)

If I have some piece of knowledge I would like to share with the community, what is the best way to do so from a Stack Exchange network point of view? Obviously "asking a question" is not welcomed, as it is not a question.

Comment: get a blog? honestly, it is really hard to put a meaningful answer to this without context. It could well be that stackoverflow simply isn't the place to put it...

Comment: Note that while you can't mark your question as community wiki, you can mark your answer as such. You can also flag your question for moderator attention, explaining and asking to make it into community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "asking a question" is not welcomed, as it is not a question.

I don't see how "Asking a Question" is not welcome - the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) explicitly mentions you can ask and [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

> It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy! – phrase it in the form of a question.

So, do the same. Frame it as a question. Perhaps leave comment stating you will be answering it yourself. You might get a better answer/solution than what you have thought of